# how to load data from google cloud storage into R using bq_load_table() from bigrquery?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use the bq_load_table() function from the BigQuery package in R (bigrquery) to load a dataset from my Google Cloud Storage bucket into memory. However, my function keeps crashing because I seem to be using the wrong arguments for the function. I am confused as to what the 'x' argument in bq_table_load() is asking for.

The following is an example of my code (assuming I have already set up / authenticated my project with bigrquery):

```
project <- 'my_project'

cloud_bucket_uri <- 'gs://myfolder/my_dateset'

sql <- 'SELECT * FROM `my_schema.my_table`'
table <- bq_project_query(project, sql)  # this creates the BigQuery table object from by query (in R) 

bq_table_save(table, cloud_bucket_uri) # this saves the table into my GCS bucket

bq_table_load(x, cloud_bucket_uri) # how to use this function?
```

In the help documentation, the arguments to the bq_table_load functions are:

```
bq_table_load(x, source_uris, ..., quiet = NA)
```

And it is stated that the x argument should be:
A bq_table, or an object coercible to a bq_table.

What should this x argument be? Because I am loading a saved table from my Google Cloud Storage bucket, and not writing anything to the bucket from BigQuery, I don't know what to use for this argument?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand in [the documentation found from rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery/versions/1.0.0/topics/api-table), you use the same argument for *bq_table_save* and *bq_table_load* :

> bq_table_save(***table***, cloud_bucket_uri) # this saves the table
>   into my GCS bucket
>
> bq_table_load(***table***, cloud_bucket_uri) # this loads the talbe from my GCS bucket

You can check it also in the page 6 on [this pdf from r-project](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf).

Comment: I did exactly that, and I get an error message saying that that the table already exists, so I can't save it

Comment: I understand that you maybe can save it in a different directory inside the bucket but what you would like is overwrite the table, right?

Comment: Hi Temu, no, I would like to save the table into my R environment, from the google cloud bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I think bq_table_load() is not meant to be used to load table into R, but to save the table in BigQuery. So the "x" here is expecting a string for a BQ table location [BQ_projectID.BQ_dataset.BQ_tableName].

If you want to load the table directly into R, use bq_table_download() instead. Alternatively, use googleCloudStorageR::gcs_get_object().